# 0 Jobs on page 2 when sorted by Recent

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Problem:
In stack overflow jobs, 0 jobs are visible on page 2, when sorted by 'recent'.

Steps to repeat:

1. Navigate to https://stackoverflow.com/jobs
2. Sort jobs by "Most Recent"
3. Click page 2 (0 jobs will appear)

Comment: I'm looking into this now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the report, Dan. I've just deployed a fix for this. It should be better now.

Comment: Hey Jason, would you mind adding a single line reason as to why the bug occurs? (Only if you have a couple of free mins, I know you're damn busy right now :))

Comment: @BhargavRao: We accidentally used the "pg" query parameter for two different things.